# How do I use hook_action_info() actions with entity_create->save() during bootstrap?

Tags: 7, entities, actions

I'm building a standalone script which uses Drupal's bootstrap because I need to render it as a page in an external application (a portal, specifically). The goal is to allow users to register for events with an Ajax call to this script.

The module I'm using is node_registration. It I'm able to create and save the entity (registration) using the API in the bootstrap script with no problem. However, there should be an e-mail that gets sent to the user after registering. This action does work when they register for an event in the CMS (not the external app/portal).

I'm fairly new to Drupal (not PHP), so I'm open to any suggestions. Perhaps I should be making an AJAX call to the form URL in Drupal?

This is the code I am using.

```
$eventRegistration = entity_create('node_registration', array(
  'uid' => 0,
  'type' => 'event', //bundle
  'node_type' => 'event',
  'nid' => $nid, 
  'email' => $email,
  'slots' => 1, 
  'author_id' => 0, 
  'uid' => 0,  
  'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'update' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'secret' => _node_registration_secret(),)
);

$eventRegistration->save();
```

The function I'm looking to have automatically executed is `node_registration_send_mail_action()`, and it is included in node_registration.actions.inc.

Here is what I'm using to bootstrap Drupal:

```
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: Hmmr. Unless you're not at a high enough bootstrap level the action hook(s) should be called if the node is saved. Are you sure its on every node save -- or when Cron runs that the emails are supposed to be sent out from drupal?

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the script code, including the part that bootstraps Drupal. Without to see that code, it is not possible to point out something wrong in your code.

Comment: That was my original though, but I'm calling **drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL)**.  

Do you think I need to call something separately to include the actions?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your question.  It is being called after every registration.  I tested this by placing a die() call in the function itself.  It only died if I registered through the site.

Comment: I went and added it from my comment below in the first answer.  Thanks!

Comment: You also define `DRUPAL_ROOT`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, DRUPAL_ROOT is defined, and it's set to be four levels up from the current working directory of the script (getcwd() . '/../../../')